# Embed in a command won't send, all other embeds do

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Despite all the other Embeds working, and this being a direct copy and paste, the "await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, embed=embed)" keeps sending errors in the log though and I don't understand it. "Bot" is what most people call client

I've already tried using bot.say() to see if the channel was the issue, and I've tried rearranging the embed statement to declare as close as possible to the send. All of the other embeds in the code use the same format with barely any changes, I even copy-pasted it to make it exact. I tried commenting on all the parts of it out, the only parts that can be causing it are either one of the add_field statements or the initial setup, but I've used that before.

````
                title = "Rock Paper Scissors", 
                description = ctx.message.author.name, 
                color = discord.Color.red()
            )

            if(winner == "tie"):

                embed.set_thumbnail(url = "//https://i.imgur.com/RcnDdIR.png")
                embed.add_field(name= "Winner", value= "It was a tie! Both chose " + choice + "!", inline=False)
                embed.add_field(name= "Chips", value= users[ctx.message.author.id]["chips"], inline=False)

                await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, embed=embed)
                economy["rps"]["played"] += 1

                print (ctx.message.author.name + " Played Rock Paper Scissors, but tied")

                f = open(logname, "a")
                f.write(ctx.message.author.name + " Played Rock Paper Scissors, but tied\n")
                f.close()

"THE ERROR CODE
The Casiino is open
Running on Casiino
ID: 566778084175642635
Wildcard Played Rock Paper Scissors, but tied
Ignoring exception in command rps
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\cjwil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 50, in wrapped
    ret = yield from coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\cjwil\Desktop\casiino\bot.py", line 479, in rps
    await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, embed=embed)
  File "C:\Users\cjwil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 1152, in send_message
    data = yield from self.http.send_message(channel_id, content, guild_id=guild_id, tts=tts, embed=embed)
  File "C:\Users\cjwil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 200, in request
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: BAD REQUEST (status code: 400)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\cjwil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 846, in process_commands
    yield from command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\cjwil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 374, in invoke
    yield from injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\cjwil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 54, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(e) from e
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: HTTPException: BAD REQUEST (status code: 400)"```

"I want The embed to send without any issues and without throwing errors."
````

Comment: It would be useful if you provided the error that is being returned. Reading and understanding error messages are a vital aspect of programming/debugging.

Comment: Please also includ e the version of discord.py that you are using: `print(discord.__version__)`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `users[ctx.message.author.id]["chips"]` is a `Member` object.  Try explicitly getting its string representation to use in the embed:

```
embed.add_field(name= "Chips", value=str(users[ctx.message.author.id]["chips"]), inline=False)
```

Comment: Thanks, but sadly it didn't work, I commented all the other statements out in trials, it seems that it's coming from one of the other add_field statements

Comment: It might be the description, try wrapping that in a `str`. Somewhere you're setting part of this embed equal to a `Member` object

Comment: I meant the `description = ctx.message.author` line. Change it to `description = str(ctx.message.author)`

Comment: Ok that fixed that, but now I'm getting a somewhat dif error message, i was supposed to use author.name, i changed the error log in the main post to what im getting now

Comment: That `url` doesn't look like a url, maybe that's it